# MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT is returning Null value even after deleting data from Database

Tags: jdbc, mule, mule-el

I have a Mule flow in which I have a Database delete operation :-

```
<jdbc-ee:connector name="Database_Global" dataSource-ref="DB_Source" validateConnections="true" queryTimeout="-1" pollingFrequency="0" doc:name="Database">
    <jdbc-ee:query key="DeleteQuery" value="delete from getData where ID=10"/>
    </jdbc-ee:connector>

<flow name="DeleteFlow" doc:name="restFlow1">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="8082" doc:name="HTTP"/>
<jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" queryKey="DeleteQuery" queryTimeout="-1" connector-ref="Database_Global" doc:name="Database (JDBC)"/>
<logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-payload value="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

Now the issue is `flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']` is returning null even the row exists and is deleted from Database ... I am using Mule 3.5 anypoint studio with JDBC ee connector ..
One more issue I like to address ... I need something like :-

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
 <when expression="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']==null] ">
<logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows... Failed!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-payload value="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows ...Failed!!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 </when>
<otherwise>
<set-payload value="Deleted Successfully !!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 </otherwise>
</choice>
```

just after the **jdbc-ee:outbound-endpoint** where I can display success message if row is deleted and failure message if not ... But I am getting error like :-

Root Exception stack trace:

> [Error: unresolvable property or identifier: ]] 
>   [Near : {... flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']==null] ....}]

How can I achieve it ... Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: it's `MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT` not `MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT`.

Comment: Thanks David ... That part is solved .. but how do I use it in Choice router ... I am still getting the exception

Comment: Hi David ... I tried using <when expression="#[flowVars'MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT'.equals(0) ]"> <logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows... Failed!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>  but even if the value is 1, then also it is executing the same message .. it's not going to else or default block

Comment: Does `<logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows"` throw an exception or does it log null?

Comment: Nope David .. It doesn't give any exception ... here is the code:- <choice doc:name="Choice">
 <when expression="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT'==0]]">
<logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows... Failed!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-payload value="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows ...Failed!!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 </when>
<otherwise>
<set-payload value="Deleted Successfully !!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 </otherwise>
</choice>

Comment: If I use the above condition ... now the control goes to else block always and Print Deleted Successfully !! in logs whatever be the situation .. It always execute the default block now

Comment: <logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']] rows successfully print the row updated ... if the row is deleted then it returns 1 and incase if there is no row with that id and no delete takes place it returns 0 ... based on these value I want to print the message in log ..

Comment: You have a syntax error. The closing `]` is at the wrong place. It should be: `<when expression="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']==0]">`

Comment: Thank David .. you saved me .. It's working now :) ... actually I tried various options like #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT'==0]] and #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT==0']] and also #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT'.equals(0)]]... but nothing worked ... Now it's working ... Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Finally the working code is `MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT` :-

```
<choice doc:name="Choice">
 <when expression="#[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UPDATE_COUNT']==null] ">
<logger message="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows... Failed!!!" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
<set-payload value="Deleted #[flowVars['MULE_JDBC_UDATE_COUNT']] rows ...Failed!!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 </when>
<otherwise>
<set-payload value="Deleted Successfully !!!" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
 </otherwise>
</choice>
```